# Use date reference is a vlookup formula

Tags: excel, vlookup, date-range

I have attached a printscreen to make it easier to understand my question.

I'm creating a supply management woorkbook. Income will refer to the purchases and outcome the resale of this purchases. Because there will be price variations, I'm looking for a formula to insert on Outcome Total Price that will return the purchase price of the item sold to deduct from the total value of my stock.

I don't know if it's possible to use a second reference on vlookup formula, like to return the price of product A with the condition that it has to be before the date 19/09/2016.

Adriano

[image: print screen]

Comment: What have you tried? Is your goal to return the value or is your goal to use Vlookup? Because Vlookup is not the way to tackle this. Is your data always sorted ascending by date in B? Do you want the formula just in F7? Or do you want to copy it down? Should the formula return the price of the latest purchase up to the current row or all rows of data? Your question leaves a lot of things unclear.  Do NOT put clarification into comments. Edit your question and post a comment when you've done that.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. It's a bit hard to explain that... but have a look if it's more understandable now

Comment: Is your data guaranteed to be sorted by date????

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there will be no more than one entry for any given product on any given day, and assuming the data is ordered chronologically, try this in F3 and copy down

```
=IF(E3>0,SUMPRODUCT($D2:D$3,--($A2:A$3=A3),--($B2:B$3=MAX($B2:B$3))),"")
```